# How to add libraries path to a compiler

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, compilation, g++

Hi I'm trying to compile from command line with `g++` but I'm using in my project boost classes and I'm getting error that they cannot be found. I know about `-I` switch but this requires that I have to type this path every time I'm compiling this file. So how can I add them that I do not have to specify them every time I use them?

Comment: why don't you use a Makefile?

Comment: Or perhaps even CMakeFiles :-)

Answer (score 2):

One way is to create a permanent `alias` in your `bashrc`/`tcshrc`/... file.

```
alias gboost='g++ -I /<absolute path>'
```

Now, instead of `g++` you can use `gboost` command. Once `bash`/`tcsh` is run, this `alias` will take effect.

This technique is good for stand alone files. For larger projects you can create a `Makefile` and use `make` command.